# multiple ORDER BY and LIMIT for each DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql

After `select` with `order by` from table `test`, suppose that we got the following, in which `order by letter` first and then `order by num`:

```
Query from TABLE test:

---------------
letter   num
A        10  
A        20
A        30
B        1
B        2
B        3
C        2
C        3
C        4
...
```

My question is, is it possible to get the first `num` for each `letter` and reduce the result: (`Limit 1` for each `distinct` letter)

```
Query from TABLE test:

---------------
letter   num
A        10  
B        1
C        2
...
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min()` comes to mind:

```
select a, min(num)
from t
group by a;
```

Do you have something more complex in mind?  This is very basic SQL.

Comment: Thanks! `MIN()` and `MAX()` work also for the time/date format. I thought it too complicatedly